# Is Instagram Content Publishing API available in a test environment without being a partner?

Tags: facebook, instagram-api

I'm looking at setting up an Instagram app so I can push content from my app directly to Instagram. I'm already doing this for Facebook, LinkedIn, and Twitter.

I know that Instagram is in the middle of moving to the Facebook Graph API, and it seems like there are several barriers to even start developing an app.

At the top of the [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started) link there's a blurb stating that I need to undergo "Business Verification" to use the Instagram Graph API. Do I need to do this in order to use these endpoints in sandbox mode? (Edit: I believe this must be done in order to test the non-beta aspects of the API) In addition, the [Content Publishing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing) seems to be locked down even further, requiring parternship with either Facebook or Instagram, and neither are accepting new applications.

Is there some way to test this in sandox mode without becoming a partner?

(Edit: [Testing your app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started#test) Suggests that I must do business validation in order to use the non-beta aspects, and there's no permission for publish_content, leading me to believe that I must be a business partner to even test this feature. Can anyone confirm?)

Comment: Business Verification is part of the review process, and that starts only after you have developed and tested your app. While your app is in dev mode, you should be able to test these features with users that have a role in the app, same as with how it works for Graph API.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same but this is so bureaucratic and rigid that I can't even see available the instagram_content_publish permission available to me. I already have our company verified.

Answer (score 1):

Januray 26, 2021
The Content Publishing beta has ended and all developers can now publish media on Instagram Professional accounts. Refer to the Content Publishing guide for usage details.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing